# window. scrollBy value for Vaadin Application

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

Is it possible to set the 'scrollBy' value in a vaadin application? 
'scrollBy' = amount of pixels by which the scroll occurs.

I tried UI.getCurrent().setScrollTop() but it didnt have any effect. 
My views are loaded inside a Panel. I tried setting scrollTop to that also but didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all your Views are located inside a Panel, the Panel itself will have a scrollbar. Therefore you can call `setScrollTop()` on the panel.

```
int offset = 30;
Panel p = new Panel();
p.setScrollTop(offset);
```